# php 5 constructor _construct does not work

Tags: php

We have php 5.3.0 and I would like to use the constructor _construct.
But somehow this constructor is not called when an instance of the class is made.
And old constructor ( function ClassName() ) on the other hand works.
Should not the new version (_construct) work with php 5.3.0 ?

Another thing I would like to build an constructor with arguments.
But the parent constructor has none. If I try to build this php tells me the constructor has to have the same construct like the parent constructor. Is this so ?

Example:

```
abstract class Foo{

   function _construct(){
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo{

   function _construct($arg){
     parent::_construct();
   } 
}
```

Thanks for replies

Comment: I couldn't figure out at teh first go that it is 2 underscore symbols at side by side :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__construct()` (two underscores)

Second question: fix the underscores in `__construct()` and see if this is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
abstract class Foo {
    function __construct() { } 
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    function __construct($arg){
        parent::_construct();
    } 
}
```